# Multivariate second order polynomial regression python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, scipy-optimize

I am  dealing with multivariate regression problems.
My dataset is something like X = (nsample, nx) and Y = (nsample, ny).
nx and ny may vary based on different dataset of different case to study, so they should be general in the code.

I would like to determine the coefficients for the multivariate polynomial regression minimizing the root mean square error.
I thought to split the problem in ny different regressions, so for each of them my dataset is X = (nsample, nx) and Y = (nsample, 1). So, for each depended variable (Uj) the second order polynomial has the following form:

[image]

I coded the function in python as:

```
def func(x,nx,pars0,pars1,pars2):
  y = pars0 #pars0 = bias
  for i in range(nx):
    y = y + pars1[i]*x[i] #pars1 linear coeff (beta_i in the equation)
    for j in range(nx):
        if (j < i ):
            continue
        y = y + pars2[i,j]*x[i]*x[j] 
        #diag pars2 =  coeff of x^2 (beta_ii in the equation)
        #upper triangle pars2 = coeff of x_i*x_k (beta_ik in the equation)
  return y
```

and the root mean square error as:

```
def resid(nsample,nx,pars0,pars1,pars2,x,y):
  res=0.0
  for i in range(nsample):
    y_pred = func(nx,pars0,pars1,pars2,x[i])
    res=res+((y_pred - y[i]) ** 2)
  res=res/nsample
  res=res**0.5
  return res
```

To determine the coefficients I thought to use scipy.optmize.minimize but it does not work [example_1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/69092/how-to-minimize-mean-square-error-using-python) [example_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985348/why-does-scipy-optimize-minimize-gives-me-such-a-bad-fit).
Any ideas or advices? Should I use sklearn?

-> EDIT: Toy test data nx =3, ny =1

```
0.20    -0.02   0.20    1.0229781
0.20    -0.02   0.40    1.0218807
0.20    -0.02   0.60    1.0220439
0.20    -0.02   0.80    1.0227083
0.20    -0.02   1.00    1.0237960
0.20    -0.02   1.20    1.0255770
0.20    -0.02   1.40    1.0284888
0.20    -0.06   0.20    1.0123552
0.24    -0.02   1.40    1.0295350
0.24    -0.06   0.20    1.0125935
0.24    -0.06   0.40    1.0195798
0.24    -0.06   0.60    1.0124632
0.24    -0.06   0.80    1.0131748
0.24    -0.06   1.00    1.0141751
0.24    -0.06   1.20    1.0153533
0.24    -0.06   1.40    1.0170036
0.24    -0.10   0.20    1.0026915
0.24    -0.10   0.40    1.0058125
0.24    -0.10   0.60    1.0055921
0.24    -0.10   0.80    1.0057868
0.24    -0.10   1.00    1.0014004
0.24    -0.10   1.20    1.0026257
0.24    -0.10   1.40    1.0024578
0.30    -0.18   0.60    0.9748765
0.30    -0.18   0.80    0.9753220
0.30    -0.18   1.00    0.9740970
0.30    -0.18   1.20    0.9727272
0.30    -0.18   1.40    0.9732258
0.30    -0.20   0.20    0.9722360
0.30    -0.20   0.40    0.9687567
0.30    -0.20   0.60    0.9676569
0.30    -0.20   0.80    0.9672319
0.30    -0.20   1.00    0.9682354
0.30    -0.20   1.20    0.9674461
0.30    -0.20   1.40    0.9673747
0.36    -0.02   0.20    1.0272033
0.36    -0.02   0.40    1.0265790
0.36    -0.02   0.60    1.0271688
0.36    -0.02   0.80    1.0277286
0.36    -0.02   1.00    1.0285388
0.36    -0.02   1.20    1.0295619
0.36    -0.02   1.40    1.0310734
0.36    -0.06   0.20    1.0159603
0.36    -0.06   0.40    1.0159753
0.36    -0.06   0.60    1.0161890
0.36    -0.06   0.80    1.0153346
0.36    -0.06   1.00    1.0159790
0.36    -0.06   1.20    1.0167520
0.36    -0.06   1.40    1.0176916
0.36    -0.10   0.20    1.0048287
0.36    -0.10   0.40    1.0034699
0.36    -0.10   0.60    1.0032798
0.36    -0.10   0.80    1.0037224
0.36    -0.10   1.00    1.0059301
0.36    -0.10   1.20    1.0047114
0.36    -0.10   1.40    1.0041287
0.36    -0.14   0.20    0.9926268
0.40    -0.08   0.80    1.0089013
0.40    -0.08   1.20    1.0096265
0.40    -0.08   1.40    1.0103305
0.40    -0.10   0.20    1.0045464
0.40    -0.10   0.40    1.0041031
0.40    -0.10   0.60    1.0035650
0.40    -0.10   0.80    1.0034553
0.40    -0.10   1.00    1.0034699
0.40    -0.10   1.20    1.0030276
0.40    -0.10   1.40    1.0035284
0.40    -0.10   1.60    1.0042166
0.40    -0.14   0.20    0.9924336
0.40    -0.14   0.40    0.9914971
0.40    -0.14   0.60    0.9910082
0.40    -0.14   0.80    0.9903772
0.40    -0.14   1.00    0.9900816
```

Comment: Can you share some test data?

Comment: I've edited the question adding some toy test data I am using to test my code.

Comment: What are expected values of the `pars`'? These are the variables which need to be optimized correct?

Comment: Also, I did generate some values for the `pars` values, but when I run the result through `resid` it fails at `y_pred = func(nx,pars0,pars1,pars2,x[i])`, presumably because `nx` in `resid` gets passed to `x` in `func`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I finally came up with a solution. The problem can be seen as linear using a change of variables. I used [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions) to build the model. After some tests on real cases it works really well

Answer (score 3):

Minimizing error is a huge, complex problem. As such, a lot of very clever people have thought up a lot of cool solutions. Here are a few:

(out of all of them, I think [bayesian optimization with sklearn](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/bayesian-optimization.html) might be a good choice for your use case, though I've never used it)

(also, delete the last "s" in the image url to see the full size)

### Random approaches:

- [genetic algorithms](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3#:%7E:text=A%20genetic%20algorithm%20is%20a,offspring%20of%20the%20next%20generation.): formats your problem like chromosomes in a genome and "breeds" an optimal solution (a personal favorite of mine)

[image: ga process]

- [simulated anealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#:%7E:text=Simulated%20annealing%20(SA)%20is%20a,space%20for%20an%20optimization%20problem.): formats your problem like hot metal being annealed, which attempts to move to a stable state while losing heat

[image: Simulated anealing]

- [random search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search#:%7E:text=Random%20search%20(RS)%20is%20a,%2C%20or%20black%2Dbox%20methods.): better than it sounds. randomly tests a verity of input variables.

[image: Random Search Image]

- [Grid Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization): Simple to implement, but often less effective than methods which employ true randomness (duplicate exploration along particular axis of interest. This strategy often wastes computational resources)

[image: Grid Search Image]

A lot of these come up in [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization) for ML models.

### More Prescriptive Approaches:

- [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#:%7E:text=Gradient%20descent%20is%20a%20first,the%20direction%20of%20steepest%20descent.): uses the gradient calculated in a differentiable function to step toward local minima

[image: Gradient Descent]

- [DeepAR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynYnZywayC4&t=19m38s): uses Bayesian optimization, combined with random search, to reduce loss in hyperparameter tuning. While I believe this is only available on AWS, It looks like [sklearn has an implementation of Bayesian optimization](https://thuijskens.github.io/2016/12/29/bayesian-optimisation/)

[image: Baysian Optimization]

- [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html): I know you're already using this, but there are 15 different algorithms that can be used by changing the `method`  flag.

### The rub

while error minimization is simple conceptually, in practice complex error topologies in high dimensional spaces can be very difficult to traverse efficiently. It harkens to local and global extrema, the [explore/exploit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem, and our mathematical understanding of what computational complexity even is. Often, a good error reduction is accomplished through a combination of thorough understanding of the problem, and experimentation with multiple algorithms and hyperparameters. In ML, this is often referred to as hyperparameter tuning, and is a sort of "meta" error reduction step, if you will.

[image: ay, theres the rub]

note: feel free to recommend more optimization methods, I'll add them to the list.

Comment: I would add gradient descent (and even put it on the top of the list). Nice list by the way !

Answer (score 1):

I have a example using Simulated Annealing, as mentioned in the nice list in this thread.

First, I need to load the data and define the objective function. I saved your data in `data.csv` and loaded with

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("../data.csv", sep="   ", header=None, engine='python')
```

And fetch your values with

```
X = data[ [0,1,2] ].values
Y = data[ 3 ].values
```

I define your poly function with

```
from itertools import combinations

def poly_function(X, beta):
    X_dimension = X.shape[1]

    i,j = zip( *list(combinations( range(X_dimension), 2)) )
    X_cross = X[:,i] * X[:,j] 
    X_expanded = np.concatenate([X,X**2,X_cross] , axis=1)
    
    assert X_expanded.shape[1] == beta.shape[0], "Expect beta to be of size {}".format(X_expanded.shape[1])
    
    return np.matmul(X_expanded, beta)
```

For Simulated Annealing we simply need objective

```
def obj(beta,X=X,Y=Y):
    
    Y_hat = poly_function(X, beta)
    
    BOOSTER = 10**5
    
    return BOOSTER * np.mean( (Y-Y_hat)**2 )**.5
```

and some proposals

```
def small_delta(beta):
    new_beta = beta.copy()
    
    random_index = np.random.randint(0,new_beta.shape[0])
    
    new_beta[ random_index ] += (np.random.random() - .5) * .01
 
    return new_beta

def large_delta(beta):
    new_beta = beta.copy()
    
    random_index = np.random.randint(0,new_beta.shape[0])
    
    new_beta[ random_index ] += np.random.random() - .5 
 
    return new_beta
```

And random start

```
def random_beta():
    return np.random.random(size=9)
```

And SA with

```
import frigidum


local_opt = frigidum.sa(random_start=random_beta, 
                        neighbours=[small_delta, large_delta], 
                        objective_function=obj, 
                        T_start=10**2, 
                        T_stop=10**-12, 
                        repeats=10**3, 
                        copy_state=frigidum.annealing.copy)
```

The RMSE I found with your data was around `0.026254` with beta

```
array([ 7.73168440e+00,  2.93929578e+00,  4.10133180e-02, -1.37266444e+01,
       -3.43978686e+00, -1.12816177e-02, -1.00262307e+01, -3.12327590e-02,
        9.07369588e-02])
```

where you need to know it is build up as `(X1,X2,X3,X1**2, X2**2, X3**2, X1*X2,X1*X3,X2*X3)`

---

A longer run with more repeats can give me a error of `0.026150` with beta

```
array([ 7.89212770e+00,  3.24138652e+00,  1.24436937e-02, -1.41549553e+01,
       -3.31912739e+00, -5.54411310e-03, -1.08317125e+01,  2.09684769e-02,
        6.84396750e-02])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `statsmodels`library combined with the explanation from this link to fit polynomial models.
https://ostwalprasad.github.io/machine-learning/Polynomial-Regression-using-statsmodel.html